# How can I customize the spaces between consecutive equations on latex?

Tags: latex, report, equation

I am working on my thesis (a report type file) in which I have several consecutive equations associated to some mathematical model, the thing is that those are too separate to each other and looks not pretty good, so I would like to know how can customize this. I am using a report type file and I have been around though to many pages without finding a good answer to this.

The code is the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k \in K} \sum_{i \in V_{1}}v_{ijkg} \leq d_{jg} \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in V_{1}}\sum_{j \in V_{2}} \sum_{g \in G} v_{ijkg} \leq Q_{k} \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \in V_{2}} \sum_{k \in K} v_{ijkg} \leq W_{ig}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
d_{jg}y_{jk} \geq v_{ijkg}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_{ijkg} \leq Q_{k} \ast z_{i}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_{ijkg} \leq Q_{k} \ast F_{ik}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{g \in G}v_{ijkg} \leq M \ast \sum_{s \in V} x_{sjk}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V,s \neq h} x_{shk} - \sum_{s \in V,s \neq h} x_{hsk}=0,\hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall h \in V, \hspace{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_{jkg}-u_{lkg}+Q_{k}x_{jlk} \leq Q_{k}-\sum_{i \in V_{1}}v_{ijkg}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j,l \in V_{2},j \neq l, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \in V_{2}}x_{ijk} + \sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{jik} \leq 2,\hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in V_{1}} \sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{ijk} \leq 1, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V,s \neq j}x_{sjk}=y_{jk}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k \in K}F_{ik} \leq I \ast z_{i}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{ijk} = F_{ik}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V} \sum_{p \in V} T^{c}_{sp} x_{spk} \leq SRT, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K_{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V} \sum_{p \in V} T^{h}_{sp} x_{spk} \leq SRT, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K_{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x_{spk} \in \{0,1\} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall s,p \in V,s \neq p, & \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K \hspace*{0.2 cm} \\ y_{ik} \in  \{0,1\}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} i \in V_{1} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k  \in K & \\ v_{ijkg}  \in \mathbb{Z}^{+0}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall & k \in K,  \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall  g \in G \\ z_{i} \in \{0,1\}, \hspace*{0.1 cm}  \forall i \in V_{1}&  \\ F_{ik} \in \{0,1\}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} i \in V_{1} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall  & ,k   \in K \\ u_{jkg} \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} j \in V_{2} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k  \in  & K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g  \in G
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Here is a picture of some part of the output. The equations list take two entirely sheets.

[image]

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a cross-network duplicate has already been posted: [How can I customize the spaces between consecutive equations in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509936/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily reduce the space above/below of the equations:

```
{
\addtolength{\belowdisplayskip}{-0.5ex}
\addtolength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{-0.5ex}
\addtolength{\abovedisplayskip}{-0.5ex}
\addtolength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-0.5ex}
\begin{equation}
....
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
....
\end{equation}
}
```